# How to use webpack in hot mode

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server

i'm using in my react project a library that needs to be compiled using webpack ( the library called storm-react-diagrams)

the problem is , whenever i do some changes in the library , i need to compile it using webpack , then restart the react app using npm start in order for the changes to take effect (the generated bundle.js doesn't get updated untill i use npm start ) .

How can i optomize this and just refresh the page automaticly whenever i edit the app or the library

for info :

I'm using VS code

when changing and saving a file on my react app , the page on the browser reloads and changes take effect with no problem .
unfortuanatly , this doesn't happen when i change a file in node_modules folder

webpack config file

```html
const webpack = require("webpack");
const UglifyJsPlugin = require("uglifyjs-webpack-plugin");
var path = require("path");
var plugins = [];
const production = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";

//do we minify it all
if (production) {
 console.log("creating production build");
 plugins.push(
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
   "process.env.NODE_ENV": '"development"'
  })
 );
}

/**
 * @author Dylan Vorster
 */
module.exports =
 //for building the umd distribution
 {
  entry: "./src/main.ts",
  output: {
   filename: "main.js",
   path: __dirname + "/dist",
   libraryTarget: "umd",
   library: "storm-react-diagrams"
  },
  externals: {
   react: {
    root: "React",
    commonjs2: "react",
    commonjs: "react",
    amd: "react"
   },
   "react-dom": {
    root: "ReactDOM",
    commonjs2: "react-dom",
    commonjs: "react-dom",
    amd: "react-dom"
   },
   lodash: {
    commonjs: "lodash",
    commonjs2: "lodash",
    amd: "_",
    root: "_"
   }
  },
  plugins: plugins,
  module: {
   rules: [
    {
     enforce: "pre",
     test: /\.js$/,
     loader: "source-map-loader"
    },
    {
     test: /\.tsx?$/,
     loader: "ts-loader"
    }
   ]
  },
  resolve: {
   extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"]
  },
  devtool: production ? "source-map" : "cheap-module-source-map",
 };
```

Comment: Because you're not supposed to change the files in node_modules. They are dependencies, not sources. Either change your webpack config to exclude the file in node_modules or change your workflow.

Comment: Can you show your webpack config file?

Comment: @DavinTryon

i'll include it on the question